# HP dv9000 Vista laptop won't boot from CD/DVD drive

Tags: boot, laptop, windows-vista

My HP dv9000 Vista laptop recently got the BSOD with error 0x0000c1f5.  The only way to fix this error is to be able to boot from CD/DVD and use some repair software I have.  The problem is that the laptop REFUSES to boot from any CD/DVD I try.  I've changed the boot order so the CD/DVD is first, and I can hear the drive spin up a bit upon power-up, but after a second, it spins down and then the laptop tries to boot from hard drive.  Any ideas?  (I've tried lots of CDs so it's not the media itself)  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0xc1f5 is a transaction log filesystem glitch.  You cannot boot to another Vista machine.  Generally, you get them while installing Windows Updates, though I do not know why.

If you boot up a copy of Vista SP2 (or was it SP3) or later (including Windows 7) it will automatically repair the transaction log on mount.  You can also simply attach your hard drive to another computer running Windows Vista SP2 or Windows 7.

Also, your CD-ROM drive might be faulty, or your CDs are not bootable, or your CD-ROM drive might be slightly loose (push it in, those dvs have modular drives that can sometimes come loose.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try boot from a memory stick, get into a console and then try get to your CD drive.

Comment: I was able to get it to boot from the USB drive with the Vista Recovery Disk installed, but after the "Loading" progress bar finishes, it goes to the more typical "graphical" vista loading screen (with the animated progress bar), where I can see it is accessing the hard drive.  After a few seconds, I'm back to the same BSOD with 0x0000c1f5 error!

I found a video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwSvIhyZRVc) that suggests using SysRescCD.  What do you think of that?  It doesn't look as easy to install on a USB stick though.

Thanks, Scott

Comment: I can't comment on what you'd do to repair the installation from systemrescuecd because i haven't used it for that purpose, but here is the instructions for installing to USB: http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_How_to_install_SystemRescueCd_on_an_USB-stick#B.29_Recommended_USB_installation_method_from_Windows